# SF novel about a machine killing inhabitants because of not recognizing them because of data lost after magnetic storm

Tags: story-identification, novel, robots

I'm looking for a Science Fiction novel I read in the early 2000's.

In a dystopian city emptied of its inhabitants, a stranger arrives. He speaks with a resident, then is eliminated by a police machine which controls everyone. Then a magnetic storm occurs and the machine forgets all its data. It no longer recognizes the inhabitants and then eliminates them one by one...

Could someone help me to find out the name and the title of this novel?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall what the cover of the book looked like?

Comment: If the city is emptied of its inhabitants when the stranger arrives, who is he speaking with?

Comment: DavidW
Unfortunately no.
@OrganicMarble
Some of the inhabitants were able to escape surveillance of the machine like Marcus who was the one the stranger spoke to.
The machine was called "The Eye"